# Station ID - more than IP

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on internal PHP application where users login only from our network (we are on dedicated IP and application is checking $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and if is match our IP go thru if not - Bye

However how I can identify from which station user is login ?
Using cookie not gonna work - those are windows station working under control MS StedyState and all cookies are deleted every login
I don't need nothing fancy like full MAC address just any unique ID (can not be application username - because users use different stations)

Any ideas ?
Maybe Javascript is able to grab some Unique detail from station's browser (IE 8) and pass this as hidden input?

bensiu

Comment: var dump the $_SERVER and see what you have

Comment: AFAIK you can't rely on $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to be the real IP of the request. You can fake that on the client side.

Comment: @controlfreak123 you are wrong, whatever you mean

Comment: Second'ing Col. Shrapnel. If you fake the ip address in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] then the server won't know where to send the webpage request back. The only way you can kinda fake it is using a proxy server, however if the terminals are using SteadyState and on an internal network as the OP says, this not really practical (especially if the workstations are locked down to now allow new installs or anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's going to happen. You won't get the MAC anyway unless it is a very simple network. If this is an internal thing, perhaps you could deploy something that changes to the User Agent string. You could probably just make an Active-X or something and just have the users run it once. The User Agent could be modified to take the Mac address of the first NIC or something like that. Just an idea.

Comment: Can you develop an Active-X part...
I got access to each station, so I can place a file on each one eg. unique_id.txt with id inside, how I can read this file via javascript / active-x and place content in eg hidden input ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any sort out outgoing proxy between you and your application, then it can be configured to pass an [X_FORWARD_IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) which is by no ways secure (any other client could pass it as well) but it could be configured to indicate which internal ip the original request was from.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) in the past and changed the user agent on each machine to be a unique id (mainly used prism because it is very easy to change the user agent in the config file on install and lock it to no editing for standard users).

I just wonder though, couldn't you use the internal IP address as the unique identifier as the IP should be unique to each workstation. If you are using active directory you could probably use ldap from php to check who (which user) is logged in on any particular workstation.